# Visual Studio: copy dependent DLLs to target folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process, native

I realize that this question has been asked before - but none of the answers apply to my specific case:

- I have a solution containing a native C++ EXE project, which in turn depends on 40+ native C++ DLL projects (in the same solution).
- The EXE project has the usual *Debug*, *Release* (and *Profile*) configuration, but since them same source code base is used to build three different applications (say *A1*, *A2* and *A3*). In addition, it targets x32 and x64, so that's a total of 3 x 3 x 2 = 18 project configurations.
- The DLL projects are shared by all three target applications, so there are only 3 (*Debug*, *Release*, *Profile*) times 2 (x32, x64) = 6 configurations.
- Since the EXE project depends on the DLLs, it needs to copy the relevant output of the DLL projects to its target folder (or a subfolder thereof) whenever they are modified.

How would you handle updating of the DLLs?

- A post-build action in each DLL project doesn't work (well), as it would have to copy the DLL to the relevant output folder of *A1*, *A2* and *A3*. Any change in an output folder results in having to modify the post-build action in each of the 50 DLL projects.
- I currently added the DLLs themselves as project items to the EXE project, and configured a custom build tool to copy it to the output folder. But that requires me to add each DLL 6 times, so I end up with 6 x 50 = 300 DLLs!

What I really need is something like a Copy Local option, which unfortunately only works assemblies. Do solution do you suggest to simplify this build setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I'd do is to put all DLLs in a single folder (specific to Debug/Release etc), and copy them back to the appropriate output folder of your EXE.

This can be done in only two actions:

- Set the output directory of all DLLs to a folder like `$(ConfigurationName)_$(PlatformShortName)`

  - select all DLL projects
  - right-click -> propoerties
  - select all configurations and all platform
  - set the output dir
- Add a post-build action to the EXE project, common to all configurations that copies `$(ConfigurationName)_$(PlatformShortName)\*.dll` to `$(TargetDir)`

**EDIT**

There is a problem in the second step since the `$(ConfigurationName)` of your EXE is not the same as your DLL projects. Not sure but maybe you can have a way to deduce the corresponding configuration, in order to still have a single post-build event for all your 18 configs. It can be a new SO question:)

Comment: Excellent! Why didn't I think about it before?

Comment: Yes, I noticed. But that's manageable - it just means that there will be three slightly different post-build actions.

Answer (score 0):

This works on VisualStudio 2019 (maybe previous versions also but not tried)

I tried several ways and this is the best compromise:

- copied to the final target folder (the most important !)
- copied in project bin folder
- appears in the VS project view
- can have different x64/x86 files
- renamable (label `Link`)

Edit your *.vcxproj file and add this `ItemGroup` like any other

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="MyDllFolder\myDll.dll" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Link="myDll.dll"/>

  <!-- x86/x64 different dlls -->
  <None Include="MyDllFolder\x86\myDll2_x86.dll" Link="myDll2_x86.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory Condition="$(PlatformTarget) == x86">PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Include="MyDllFolder\x64\myDll2_x64.dll" Link="myDll2_x64.dll">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory Condition="$(PlatformTarget) == x64">PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

[image: Visible dll file in the project]

Inspired from [Automatic copy files to output during application building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779703/automatic-copy-files-to-output-during-application-building#13231222)