# Visual Studio C++ - "Copy to Output Directory" missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I created an empty C++ project in Visual Studio (2012) and in Properties window I cannot see the "Copy to Output Directory" option when I have selected some file in Solution Explorer. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CopyToOuputDirectory is not exposed in the UI of Visual Studio for C++ projects.

However, there are some workarounds. [See answers given to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779703/automatic-copy-files-to-output-during-application-building).