# How to build/copy the resource file from the C++ project to Debug Target Path?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-debugging

I have a resource file in the project which need to build/copy to the debug target path for later used.

[image]

[image]

```
IDM: Visual Studio 2013
```

Anyone know how to build/copy the resource file from C++ project to debug target path?

Comment: See the second answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779703/automatic-copy-files-to-output-during-application-building (first/accepted answer isn't suitable for single files, ignore it).

Comment: @Al-Muhandis, Thank you very much, but I'm prefer to the first one, which add the command line in the Pre-Build or Post-Build Event

Comment: Using the Pre/Post-build commands is a "dirty" way of doing it from the old VS2008- days. The sole advantage I think is that it's easier for you and co-workers to see, but I am strongly of the the opinion that more developers should be comfortable with reading and modifying MSBuild (csproj, vcxproj) files. Though MS also really needs to improve the GUIs for VC++ projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two way to accomplish this:

**Build Events**: you can add command line in the Pre-Build Event or Post-Build Event

```
COPY /y $(ProjectDir)resource.orpo $(TargetDir)resource.orpo
```

**[the other one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)**