# Visual Studio 2017 C++ Project Copy Text Files to Output Directory

Tags: copy, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

I have a number of `*.txt` files included in my Visual Studio 2017 C++ project (`*.vcxproj`).  Does anyone know how to get Visual Studio to copy these files to the output directory?

I found a similar question for [VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596508/vs2010-how-to-include-files-in-project-to-copy-them-to-build-output-directory-a), but that answer doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `*.vcxproj` file, change:

```
<Text Include="Filename.txt" />
```

to:

```
<Content Include="Filename.txt">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Then in the `*.vcxproj.filters` file, change:

```
<Text Include="Filename.txt">
    <Filter>Resource Files</Filter>
</Text>
```

to:

```
<Content Include="Filename.txt">
    <Filter>Resource Files</Filter>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 5):

Update for 2019 users:

An easy way to do this is from the file's Property Pages (right-click on the file in Solution Explorer, then click Properties).

Under Configuration Properties > General, change Item Type to "Copy file."  By default, this will create a copy of the file in the build destination directory.  Once you hit Apply, a new property page called Copy File will appear on the left where you can customize this behavior.

[image: Configuration Properties Page]

Answer (score 0):

In a VS2019 c++ console project it was just a litlle different:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Run.bat">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</DeploymentContent>

      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>

    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```