# No "Copy to Output Directory" for DLL using Visual Studio 2015, C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I understand this question has been asked many times, but something is different in VS2015.

I Click on my project, select Add Existing and add my DLL.

Then I right click on the DLL and go into Properties, but I can only see 3 properties:

`Excluded From Build
 Content
 Item Type`

Other questions on Stack overflow answer this issue with

> Use Project + Add Existing Item and select the DLL. Select the added
>   file in the Solution Explorer window. In the Properties window, change
>   the Copy to Output Directory setting to "Copy if newer".

See:  [Are there any better ways to copy a native dll to the bin folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863419/are-there-any-better-ways-to-copy-a-native-dll-to-the-bin-folder)

But in my VS2015, I don't have an option to `Copy to Output Directory`

Why is this? What is missing? 
I tried placing the DLL under Source files and under Resource Files, and I can't seem to pace it under References, because it only lets me pick another project.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this property is just hidden for C++ projects. How unfortunate

Answered Here:

[Automatic copy files to output during application building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779703/automatic-copy-files-to-output-during-application-building)