# can Visual Studio C++ Express (2010) Automatically Copy Dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Apologies for for the newbie question but I come from Visual C#, and all I'm looking to do is roughly the same capability with that IDE when it comes to dependencies and resources:

Simply: How can I add a dependency DLL, and have it automatically copy to my compile targets destination folder?

I understand VC2010 Express has no Resource editor, and that's fine, I'm looking to simply add these things to my "project" and have them copy over on build.

Just need to know if its possible or not, or if that's only available in the full version, if at all.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this should work for you:  [visual-studio-copy-dependent-dlls-to-target-folder](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4956005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, one needs to realize that Visual C++ is the kind of IDE that grows hair on your chest and sprout grey hairs on your head.

I actually didn't know about this possibility, of "Post" and "Pre" build actions.

`Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Build Events > Post-Build Event`
was exactly where I needed to place my command line of

`copy "$(ProjectDir)SDL.dll" "$(OutDir)SDL.dll"`

Perfect. I just need to remember to do this with all my necessary dependencies